# Plymouth splash not showing, purple and black on boot

Tags: 11.10, boot, nvidia, grub2, plymouth

I've got Ubuntu 11.10 on Asus machine with Nvidia G-Force 210M,...everything works fine, but bootscreen Plymouth splash does not show...

First time I've had big resolution logo so I Googled some info about that problem and tried some things> plymouth fix, editing /etc/default/grub changing setup at startup manager...but it did not work...now i only have a purple screen for a while, then a black screen and then the system starts...

Can you help me figure out how to get the Plymouth splash working? thanx..

Comment: This is very vague.  You need to explain what you actually did.  Posting your `/etc/default/grub` would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try Super Burg Manager:

[‘Super Boot Manager’ eases BURG, GRUB, Plymouth tweaking pains](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/super-boot-manager-eases-burg-grub-plymouth-tweaking-pains/)